# Scala, ZIO, Sttp, Circe - how to map error response to custom trait in sttp client using circe?

Tags: scala, circe, zio, sttp

I have a simple `sttp` client implementation:

```
  basicRequest.auth
    .get(...)
    .response(asJsonEither[GeneralTrait, MyResponse])
    .send(backend)
    .map(_.body.left.map {
      case HttpError(body, statusCode) => mapToTraitImplementation(statusCode, body)
      case DeserializationException(_, _) => SomeSerializationError(s"Deserialization error")
    })
    .flatMap(ZIO.fromEither(_))
```

`GeneralTrait` looks like:

```
sealed trait GeneralTrait extends Throwable
```

And it has few same structure implementations:

```
final case class FirstError(msg: String, code: Int) extends GeneralTrait
```

But when I run this client, I always get an error `DeserializationException` because it could not parse error response to `GeneralTrait`. When I changed this:

```
.response(asJsonEither[GeneralTrait, MyResponse])
```

to

```
.response(asJsonEither[FirstError, MyResponse])
```

everything is mapped correctly and it does not return `DeserializationException`, it chooses first case `HttpError(body, statusCode) =>`.
But I have multiple implementations of this trait and I would like to have `trait` here if it is possible:

```
.response(asJsonEither[GeneralTrait, MyResponse])
```

How should I fix this? Is it even possible to do that?

**EDIT:**
I'm using `Circe` serialization. I also added `Codecs`:

```
  implicit val decoderGeneralTrait: Codec[GeneralTrait] = deriveConfiguredCodec
  implicit val decoderFirstError: Codec[FirstError] = deriveConfiguredCodec
```

Comment: Which JSON library are you using, and how is the deserializer for `GeneralTrait` defined?

Comment: Circe. I edited post and showed how I added decoders

Comment: Can you try using `decoderGeneralTrait` to decode an example response and checking if this works correctly?

Comment: I used it. I have added these implicits to client code and tried to get response as `.response(asJsonEither[GeneralTrait, MyResponse])`, but it failed. It always returns `DeserializationException`. With concrete implementation it works fine.

Comment: @adamw any other suggestions/solutions?

Comment: Hm could you create a small reproducible example and report as a bug in https://github.com/softwaremill/tapir? Will be easier to investigate :)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I reported it https://github.com/softwaremill/tapir/issues/2789